# What does "portable application" mean?

Tags: java, specifications, jpa-2.1

I am reading java persistence specification version 2.1 There is last paragraph in 25 page:

*Entity subclasses may override the property accessor methods. However, **portable applications** must not override the object/relational mapping metadata that applies to the persistent fields or properties of entity superclasses.*

So what does "portable applications" mean? Could somebody explain and provide a few exmaples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA is a specification. Multiple implementations of this specification exist: Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc. A portable application is an application that is written to work with any of these implementations.